# FreeRDP clipboard & files

Tags: rdp

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: использую FreeRDP + буфер обмена. Так вот, текст копируется нормально в обе стороны, а файлы - нет. В стандартном клиенте Windows (mstsc) это работает, а здесь у меня не получилось. Кто может помочь с этим?

Comment: @dsarovsky, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Для rdesktop решение выглядит так:

```
 rdesktop -5 -r disk:home=/home/user -r clipboard:CLIPBOARD 192.168.0.2 -u r_user -p pass
```

Для xfreerdp (для перенаправления домашнего каталога в windows-систему):

```
xfreerdp /v:rdp.contoso.com /home-drive
```

Или:

```
xfreerdp /v:rdp.contoso.com /drive:sharename,local_path
```

Обратите внимание, что данная нотация ключей и опция /home-drive (или /drives) доступна версиях старше, чем 1.0.1. У меня, в debian7, стоит версия 1.0.1 - и она не поддерживает редирект каталогов и опции в виде "/".

Comment: Вот что мне ответили на GitHub:
"the clipboard channel doesn't support file copies yet.
If you want to copy from your remote machine to the local machine you need to use the drive channel."

Comment: ну об этом я вам и написал