# Передача файлов в xfreerdp через буфер обмена

Tags: linux

Настроил передачу текста через буфер обмена в xfreerdp

```
xfreerdp +clipboard /u:... /f /v:...
```

Как настроить передачу файлов?

Comment: Возможно правильней +home-drive, но даже эта комбинация у меня не срабатывает, ошибка: "невозможно открыть разделяемый объектный файл: Нет такого файла или каталога"

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, поддержки копирования через буфер обмена пока нет. [Этот](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/2424) GitHub issue до сих пор открыт. Так что для передачи файлов надо настроить drive channel:

```
xfreerdp /v:rdp.contoso.com /home-drive
```

Так же посмотрите [похожий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/402399/177209) вопрос.